# Iphone5 / ios6.1.3 and Facebook SDK 3.2.1 on iOS - com.facebook.sdk Error 2 on device

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

When i run LoginUI and click cancel button,try to login than can't login again

I try to use Iphone4s / ios6.1.3 and Facebook SDK 3.2.1 on iOS than cancel login can login again.

What happend with iphone5:

`[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];`  not work

Here is my code:

```
 - (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                      state:(FBSessionState) state
                      error:(NSError *)error
    {
        switch (state) {
            case FBSessionStateOpen:
                if (!error) {
                }

        break;
    case FBSessionStateClosed:
    case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];

        break;
    default:
        break;
}

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 postNotificationName:FBSessionStateChangedNotification
 object:session];

if (error) {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Error"
                              message:error.localizedDescription
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    }
}

- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {
    return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                              allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                         completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                             FBSessionState state,
                                                             NSError *error) {
                                             [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                                 state:state
                                                                 error:error];
                                         }];
}

- (void) closeSession {
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {

    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}


- (void)sessionStateChanged:(NSNotification*)notification {

    if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {

        if (nil == self.facebook) {
            self.facebook = [[Facebook alloc]
                             initWithAppId:FBSession.activeSession.appID
                             andDelegate:nil];

            self.facebook.accessToken = FBSession.activeSession.accessTokenData.accessToken;
            self.facebook.expirationDate = FBSession.activeSession.accessTokenData.expirationDate;
        }
    } else {
        self.facebook = nil;
    }
}

- (void) Loginfb {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate =
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
    } else {   
        [appDelegate openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];
    }
```

How can I solve this? `Thanks in advance.`

Comment: Can you post the login part of the code?

Comment: I post the login part of the code,thank you

Comment: Is this logging in with an iOS system FB account? Meaning you an FB account set in the 'Settings' of the phone, yes?

Comment: yes,i click login button can login Success

Comment: i have the question about user denies 'Publish' permissions the first time

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you clearly: So the user tries to login, clicks cancel, and then tries to login again, and it fails. Is that correct?

Comment: that's right,if user click cancel than tries to login again it fails

Comment: Then please see my answer below - when you cancel, go and check the permissions in the phone's Settings - Privacy - Facebook. Your app should be set to 'off'. If that is set to off, there's no way to enable it with the FB SDK.

Comment: That's can run ,thank you！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are logging in with a system Facebook account and not using fast-app-switching to log in, the first time that the user denies 'Read' permissions, your app's access in the Facebook privacy settings of the phone is set to off.

From that point on, you will not be able to grant access using the SDK anymore. Rather, the user has to manually go into their phone's Settings - Privacy - Facebook and enable access for your app.

This does not apply for 'Publish' permissions. Even if the user denies 'Publish' permissions the first time, you can keep requesting 'Publish' permissions using the SDK.